Run a Javascript function from an Outlook Add-in Manifest file
I've setup an Outlook Add-in using an XML manifest file. I've got some buttons appearing in a menu drop down on the UI. When I click the buttons it says my request is being worked on and does nothing (I'm expecting message boxes on the click of these)

I've tried checking all the references and files involved. Double-checked the xml for the button, function is ShowAlert1:
<DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

            <!-- Message compose form -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgComposeDemoGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <!-- Function (UI-less) button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeFunctionButton1">
                  <Label resid="funcComposeButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="blue-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="blue-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="blue-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>showAlert1</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>

My function file is:
<bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/Functions.html"/>

Within Functions.html is the ref to the js file with my function:
<script src="Functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

and finally the Functions.js has my function def:
function showAlert1() {
    alert("This is an alert box!");
    
    event.completed();
}

ALL three of these files, the manifest, the functions.html and functions.js are in the same folder. I'm running a localhost and it hasn't complained in red about any of these files....
Can someone help to debug this or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks @SlavaIvanov - I had left out (event) in the post, but had it in the function file. It didn't have any affect anyway.
Am I allowed to have a javascript function that say opens a browser window? I think somehow the function isn't even running... Outlook seems to go off and get lost, never reaching my function...

Did you add Office.actions.associate to your JS file?

Why would you just explore the working example: outlook-add-in-command-demo. Here you will be interested in the manifest and functions file. Try it and gradually move to your own solution.

You may also follow the steps described in the Create add-in commands with the add-in only manifest article. Please make some effort to discover.

Thanks @SlavaIvanov - this was the issue: Office.actions.associate
I had an error with these. Buttons are now executing code...!
Noting, also needed to have my local host running at all times:

http-server -S -C localhost.crt -K localhost.key --cors . -p 3000


I had an error in the js file, specifically:  Office.actions.associate wasn't completed properly.
